# What is this line doing in the thread safe build of PHP?

Tags: php, c

I was reading the book *Extending and Embedding PHP* and came across this line in C (with related structures):

```
typedef struct {
    int sampleint;
    char *samplestring;
} php_sample_globals;
int sample_globals_id;

(((php_sample_globals*)(*((void ***)tsrm_ls))[sample_globals_id - 1])->sampleint = 5
```

The author then writes:
"Don't be concerned if you have trouble parsing that statement; it's so well integrated into the PHPAPI that some developers never bother to learn how it works."

I start to get lost around `*((void ***)tsrm_ls)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*((void ***)tsrm_ls)
```

Cast the variable `tsrm_ls` as a pointer to a pointer to a pointer and then get what is pointed to (thus you end up with a pointer to a pointer)

Looking at the rest of the code and assuming it is correct:

`tsrm_ls` is a pointer to an array of pointers to `php_sample_globals` structures.

This code looks at the `sample_globals_id-1` index into that array finds the structure it points to and then sets the `sampleint` element of that structure to 5

Comment: Why would you need a pointer to a pointer to a pointer?  Also, what is void doing there?

Comment: Void in C is used to denote untyped.  And why wouldn't you have a pointer to a pointer to a pointer.  In fact that is what this data structure is -- in C arrays are just pointers (but the data is sequential.)  Thus an array of pointers is a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: What are you saying makes sense, but I'm not well versed enough in C to be able to write this type of code myself.  Back to the books I guess, thanks for the explanations!

Comment: Yes this is a bit advanced.  I would suggest starting simple.  Learn about why `a[5] = 6` is the same as `*(a+5) = 6` for example.